# Visual Studio 2022 CPU Usage frozen at preparing data step

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cpu-usage, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to look at CPU usage with Visual Studio 2022, and I have done this before in Visual Studio 2017 without any issue, but in 2022 so far it has always gotten stuck at the preparing data step. When I hit a break point I get this view

[image: Preparing data.]

I've tried simplifying my program to make sure there isn't something weird in my code causing problems, but I get that same window just infinitely spinning in circles when I tried to profile this code

```cs
var counter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 999; i++)
{
    counter += i;
}
Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

I've had issues with this in a .net 6.0 console app, and a wpf app targeting 4.7.2

This is my Visual Studio info

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
> Version 17.0.5
> VisualStudio.17.Release/17.0.5+32112.339
> Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.8.04084
>
> Installed Version: Professional

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is potentially something that was broken in 17.0.5, usually there is a yellow flag notifying if an update is available, but when I manually checked for an update I found I could update to 17.1.1

After updating to 17.1.1 the CPU usage feature is working as expected.

Comment: Now seeing this on 17.9 today. Either that or ETW events exhausted and requires a restart of VS. It's just a shed.